# Using a C++ macro to pull out items from nested parentheses

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

In C++, using macros it is easy to pull apart arguments do the following:

```
#define printThings(stringPrinting, param1, param2) printf(stringPrinting, param1, param2)

printThings(stringPrinting, param1, param2)

// Goes to

printf(stringPrinting, param1, param2)
```

However I can't find a way to do this:

```
#define printThings(a, b) printf(?)

printThings(stringPrinting, Blarg(param1, param2))

// Goes to

printf(stringPrinting, param1, param2)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Don't write answers in comments :-P ...

Comment: @Alf, I agree variadic macros would work for n number of arguments. I just simplified the code because this was the essential problem I was having.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ; We don't yet know exactly what the question is.

Comment: I clarified the question if that helps

Comment: @DanielleEnsign: you don't have to put UNPACK there. read the comment/answer again.

Comment: @DanielleEnsign Also say farewell to that parentheses ...

Comment: @DanielleEnsign: The new stuff is a different question, as you suspected. It's still not clear what the intended use case is. The non-macro mechanism to do stuff like that is to use lambda expressions, templating and/or `std::function`.

Comment: Okay, I will post a new question with the use case, thanks for your help though.

Comment: For those that are interested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082262/using-macros-on-functions-in-an-array-to-make-gtest-typed-tests-more-succinct) is the new question, with the intended use case.

Comment: Okay, I tweaked this one a little in a way that I think still fits the intended question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just

```
#define UNPACK( a, b ) a, b
#define printThings( s, args ) printf( s, UNPACK args )
```

This is one of the staple macro idioms for advanced preprocessor stuff. The canonical technique for dealing with variadic arguments, e.g. to distribute some macro invocation over the arguments, was posted by some guy I don't remember (French?) in comp.lang.c or comp.std.c newsgroup ca 1999 I think it was, maybe later. The Boost preprocessor library as well as the Boost parameters library have lots of REALLY advanced stuff. If you want to learn. :)

---

Note 1: It looks like you really want a variadic macro, defined with `...` (three dots) instead of named arguments. I'm sure you can google that.

---

Note 2: Since macros are Evil™ it may be that you really want some variation of

```
template< class... Args >
void printThings( char const* s, Args&&... args )
{
    printf( s, std::forward<Args>( args )... );
}
```

---

Disclaimer: untested code.

Comment: Well, the answer really is: Use a variadic parameter list macro and forget about the parentheses.

Comment: Presuming what the question really is, I agree. But let's not presume. ;-)

Comment: Sometimes, it seems to be better just telling the OP _"let go what you want as (invalid) syntax"_, and just get them onto the correct path ;-) ...

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't asking the right question. I posted the essentials of what I am dealing with up above, though like I said there I can move this to a separate question if you would like.